# Can a multiclassed Divine Soul sorcerer/wizard add cleric spells to their spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, multi-classing, sorcerer

I am in a campaign where I am a multiclassed Divine Soul sorcerer 2/wizard 1. I have a paladin, a cleric, and a druid in my party. As a Divine Soul sorcerer, I have access to the cleric spell list.

Can the cleric or the paladin write cleric spells in my spellbook?
Or if I find or buy cleric spell scrolls, can I add them to my spellbook?
Why? Or why not?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Related: [Can a multi-class Bard/Wizard write spells known from Bard, into Wizard spellbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79171/33569), [Can I copy prepared Cleric spells that are also on the Wizard spell list into my spellbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103231/33569), [Can a multiclassed Wizard/Bard scribe a spell scroll for a spell they know as a bard, then copy it into their spellbook (if it's on both spell lists)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165047/33569)

Comment: 2 more: [Can a multiclass Warlock/Wizard add spells known from Warlock to the Wizard spellbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/164891/33569), [Can a multiclass Wizard/Fighter (Eldritch Knight) add EK known spells to the wizard spellbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123417/33569). (Some of these, but not all, might effectively be duplicates of one another; it may be worth discussing on [meta] whether we should have a canonical Q&A for the general case and close the others as a duplicate of that, except if there's a reason it might be unique - like the EK's spells being "wizard spells".)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Only if the spell appears on the Wizard spell list

The rule on copying spells into a wizard's spellbook in the ["Your Spellbook"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#LearningSpellsof1stLevelandHigher) sidebar says (*Player's Handbook* p. 114; emphasis added):

> When you find a **wizard spell** of 1st level or higher, you can add it to your spell book if it is of a spell level you can prepare and if you can spare the time to decipher and copy it.

The limitation is it being a wizard spell specifically, i.e. appearing on the wizard spell list, not just being on one of your class lists. So to transfer a spell it would need to be on both class's list.

You also need to be the one making the copy (there is simply no provision made which enables someone else to do it), so for one of your party members to scribe their spell to you, they would need to create a *spell scroll* of the spell, with the costs associated with that in addition to your transcribing costs.

As a side note, you aren't able to write any of your own known (sorcerer/cleric) spells to your spellbook without going through the same process. See [Can a multi-class Bard/Wizard write spells known from Bard, into Wizard spellbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79171/52137) or [Can I copy prepared Cleric spells that are also on the Wizard spell list into my spellbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103231/52137) for more details.

Comment: Note that spells not normally on that list can be added to it and consequently your spell book if a feature, such as the GGR backgrounds for example, does so.  The real problem here is that Divine Soul adds to the Sorcerer list for you, not the Wizard list.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Divine Soul sorcerers can't even read/use *spell scrolls* for cleric spells they don't know (unless they're already on the sorcerer list). Cleric spells only become sorcerer spells for you if you learn them via the sorcerer's Spellcasting feature: "**When your Spellcasting feature lets you learn or replace a sorcerer cantrip or a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher**, you can choose the new spell from the cleric spell list or the sorcerer spell list. You must otherwise obey all the restrictions for selecting the spell, and it becomes a sorcerer spell for you."

Answer (score -1):

See the "Your Spellbook" sidebar on PHB 114

No, you may only add wizard spells to your spellbook. You may not add your Sorcerer spells to that spellbook either.